# Powershell foreach in foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a CSV list of users, and I want to check if their accounts were disabled, which the scripts work simply fine, but now I want to check them approach different Domains and not just one. Is there an easy way to do it?

The code is simple and looks like this now:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csv = Import-Csv -Path “C:\temp\Users.csv”

# Check for how many users are in CSV the list
$HowManyUsers = (Get-Content C:\temp\Users.csv).Length-1
$Servers = @("D01", "D02", "D03", "D04", "D05")
$Total = 0

Foreach ($user in $csv)
{
$fname = $user.FirstName
$lname = $user.LastName

GET-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -eq $fname -and Surname -eq $lname} -Properties * | Select DisplayName, EmployeeID, Enabled
$Total++

}
```

Do I need to do another foreach or is there is simpler way of doing it? I was thinking of just doing this:

```
GET-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -eq $fname -and Surname -eq $lname} -Server $Servers -Properties * | Select DisplayName, EmployeeID, Enabled
```

But that does not work.

Comment: If performance is a concern, you better [create a lookup (hash)table](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#looking-up-entries-by-property-in-large-collections).

Comment: The `-Server` parameter for `Get-ADUser` only accepts one single server. You need to iterate for each server.

`Import-Csv` creates a array, you can use a simple `$HowManyUsers = $csv.Length`.   
Also: why `Select-Object` when you can chose the properties in `Get-ADUser`?

Comment: Why would you need to check _all_ DCs? Whether a user is disabled/enabled will automatically replicate to all the other DCs, so you usually only need to query one of them unless you have replication issues

Comment: If you do need to check each server (like if they are in different domains), then you do need two foreach statements. Note that `GivenName` and `Surname` are not unique attributes (what happens when there's more than one John Smith or they had a name change in one domain?), so try using something like ID/email address/username if possible

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example updated script. $Total is populated because powershell returns any uncaught output (i.e. the Get-ADUser command returns a result and we're not capturing in a variable, so it is returned instead).

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csv = Import-Csv -Path “C:\temp\test.csv”

# Check for how many users are in CSV the list
$HowManyUsers = $csv.Count
$Servers = @("DC1", "DC2")

# Iterate CSV
$Total = $csv | %{
    $fname=$_.FirstName
    $lname=$_.LastName
    # Iterate Servers
    $Servers | %{
        Get-ADUser -Server $_ -Filter 'GivenName -eq $fname -and Surname -eq $lname' -Properties DisplayName, EmployeeID, Enabled | where enabled -eq $false
    }
}
Write-Host "Count is: " $Total.count
```

With that said, are you sure you don't want `-SearchBase` instead of `-Server`?